# Rating stars with content :after changing the stars also before?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce wordpress site with star rating of the products, that I tweaked to my needs, but I can't get the hovered star to light up all the stars before. As I saw, the css system can't target elements before, and jQuery can't target the :after element. How can I make it work?

HTML:

```
<p class="stars"><span>
<a class="star-1" href="#">1</a>
<a class="star-2" href="#">2</a>
<a class="star-3" href="#">3</a>
<a class="star-4" href="#">4</a>
<a class="star-5" href="#">5</a>
</span></p>
```

CSS:

```
p.stars a {
border-right: none;
width: auto;
margin-right: 20px; 
display: inline-block;
text-indent: -9999px;
position: relative;
}

#main-content-in p.stars a:after { content: "\e021";  }
#main-content-in p.stars a:hover:after { content: "\e020"; }
```

Comment: using CSS: `#main-content-in p.stars a:hover ~ a:after { content: "\e021";  }` http://jsfiddle.net/X8kSb/3/

Comment: thanks, great tip, it works, but I had to add this before, to make all the stars full, so that only the following are blank: 
`#main-content-in p.stars:hover a:after { content: "\e020"; color: #741A1A; }`